# error in cloning a firebase project

Tags: android, database, android-studio, firebase

i`m trying to clone this project **https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus/tree/1.00_version_0.1_start_code** but i have an error for two days i could not bug it *Could not find property 'UniqueFirebaseRootUrl' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@5361f487.*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of missing gradle.properties files.

Create a gradle.properties file within the main directory. Make sure "Project" is selected on the dropdown right above the treeview.

[image: Missing gradle.properties]

Add the following to the file:
UniqueFirebaseRootUrl = "https://shoppinglistplspls.firebaseio.com/"

Read the [issues here](https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus/issues/12).

-- UPDATE --

**Note:**

**"shoppinglistplspls.firebaseio.com/"** must be replaced with a reference to your unique Firebase database url link that you create when you make your Firebase app. **shoppinglistplspls** is the generic app used as an example in the class, so you must make your own. (kudos for @Lyla comments)

Comment: Note that "https://shoppinglistplspls.firebaseio.com/" should be replaced with a reference to your unique Firebase database that you create when you make your Firebase app. shoppinglistplspls is the generic app used as an example in the class, but you don't have admin rights over it so you should make your own.

Comment: @Lyla, You're right. may I include it in my answer?